# Issue in tax configuration After magento upgrade

Tags: magento

I have upgrade magento from v1.4 to v1.9.
after successful upgrade magento, I have issue with tax configuration.
magento dashboard shows below error.

1. Warning tax discount configuration might result in different discounts than a customer might expect . Please see source for more details.Click here to go to Tax configuration and change your settings.
2. Warning tax configuration can result in rounding errors for store(s) : PL Germany(PL Euro Wholesale English), PL Germany(PL Germany Wholesale), PL Germany(PL Germany Retail), PL Germany(PL Euro English). Please see source for more details.Click here to go to Tax configuration and change your settings.

[image: magento tax issue]

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those messages are generated by checks located in app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Config.php

Message nr. 1 is generated by the following condition matrix (around line 753):

- Before Discount / Excluding Tax
- Before Discount / Including Tax

Msg nr. 2 is generated around line 728 when tax calculation method is based On 'Total' or 'Row' and at least one Price Display Settings has 'Including and Excluding Tax' value.